# slope of deflection of beam at center

Tags: structural-engineering

[image: image1]

[image: im2]

in the first photo , it's stated that the dy/dx at center = 0 , however , in the second photo (website) , it's stated that the dy/dx at the boundary = 0 ,which is correct ? I'm confused now
http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/education/calc-init/static-beam/support.html

Comment: The website actually states (correctly) that $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$, not $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\theta$ is supposed to be the same quantity as $dy/dx$, the picture is both drawn and labelled wrongly.

The equations correctly state that at $x=2$, $[dy/dx]_\text{AC} = [dy/dx]_\text{BC}$, but that does not mean $[dy/dx]_\text{AC} = [dy/dx]_\text{BC} = 0$!

On the other hand, $\theta$ might be some other quantity that isn't defined in your post - in which case we can't guess what it means.

Comment: Then ,  in  what  circumstances ,  will  theta  = 0??

Comment: I find it hard to believe that $\theta$ is anything other than $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$, since that's the standard assumption for small deflections and rotations. So yeah, I think the question is just wrong.

Comment: @kelvinmacks: I apologize for sounding pedantic, but $\theta = \dfrac{dy}{dx} = 0$ happens when the deflection is horizontal (or, more precisely, parallel to the beam's original longitudinal axis). For a simply-supported beam such as the one you've shown us, that only happens at the mid-span when the loading is symmetric. If the loading is asymmetric (such as in this case), then there's no way to know *a priori*. You need to do math and figure out where $\theta = 0$ (meaning $\theta=0$ is **not** one of your boundary conditions).

Comment: To  there's  no  way  to  determine  dy/ dx  =0 in  this  case .  Only  doing  the  Maths  can  find  the  dy/dx  =0... But ,  from  the  shape  of  graph ,  we  can  say  that  at  the  middle  of  graph ,  local  minimum  occur ,  so  that's  the  point  where  dy/dx  =0,  right ?

Comment: @Wasabi , when will the deflection is horizontal ? I cant imagine it

Comment: @Wasabi , do you mean if the load is loaded on the beam symmetrically  like this , then the dy/dx at the center of the beam is 0  ? http://imgur.com/a/S158N      ? http://imgur.com/a/77fYB